# Is it possible in JavaFX to not use the parent StyleSheet of a Node?

Tags: css, javafx

I would like to create a JavaFX Node hierarchy such as:

```
Region parentRegion = new Region();
Circle circle = new Circle();
parentRegion.getChildren().add(circle);
```

But I don't want the children of the parent region to use the StyleSheet of the parent.

So for example if I have the following CSS:

```
.green {
  -fx-fill: green;
}
```

And I have the following code:

```
Region parentRegion = new Region();
parentRegion.getStylesheets().add(<my CSS path>);
Circle circle = new Circle();
circle.getStyleClass().add("green");
parentRegion.getChildren().add(circle);
```

I would like the Circle to be black and not green.

Is it possible?

Comment: No; the intended behavior is precisely the behavior you say you don't want. If you only want the style to apply specifically to the parent node, you can do something like `.root.green { ... }` or `#some-id.green { ... }`.

Comment: The reason i'm asking is because I'm writing a library to convert SVG content to either an image of a group node, and I would have liked by default not to get the styles of the parent node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the child in a [`SubScene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/SubScene.html).

SubScenes do not inherit the CSS styles of their parent nodes.

**Example**

[image]

In the example, there are two circles, one circle is in the root layout pane of the main scene, the other is in a SubScene (with a light blue background) which is also in the root layout pane of the main scene.

The layout pane of the main scene (a VBox) has styles defined so that all of the child circles inherit a green fill.  However, the SubScene prevents the inheritance of CSS styles, so only the circle which is not in the SubScene is green.

*colored-circles.css*

```
.green {
    -fx-fill: green;
}

Circle {
    -fx-fill: inherit;
}
```

Note that, by default, `-fx-fill` CSS attribute values are not inherited by child nodes, hence the additional rule to have circles inherit the CSS attribute value for -fx-fill.

*StyleInheritance.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StyleInheritance extends Application {

    public static final double R = 50;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Circle circleInMainScene = new Circle(R, R, R);
        Circle circleInSubScene = new Circle(R, R, R);

        SubScene subScene = new SubScene(
                new Group(circleInSubScene),
                circleInSubScene.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(),
                circleInSubScene.getLayoutBounds().getHeight()
        );
        subScene.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, circleInMainScene, subScene);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.getStyleClass().add("green");

        Scene mainScene = new Scene(layout);

        mainScene.getStylesheets().add(
                StyleInheritance.class.getResource(
                        "colored-circles.css"
                ).toExternalForm()
        );

        stage.setScene(mainScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

There is probably also some way of accomplishing what you want via CSS rules alone rather than using a SubScene, but using a SubScene appears to work and is what I came up with.